# Pandas: how to get most frequent value in a month for each ID?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe `df` like the following:

```
df
     ID        date          values
0     0     2017-01-05         55
1     0     2017-01-08         55
2     0     2017-01-09         33
3     1     2017-01-05         27
4     1     2017-01-08         78
5     1     2017-01-09         78
```

I would like to get the most frequent value for each month and for each ID, so

```
df1
     ID    YearMonth   value
0    0      2017-01      55
1    1      2017-01      78
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['ID', df.date.dt.month])['values'].apply(lambda x: x.mode())`

Comment: @user3483203 you should make that an answer, though I think it will currently break if there's multiple years represented in the dates

Answer (score 2):

This solution is an improvement on the answer in the comments. It matches your expected output more closely.

```
(df.groupby(['ID', df.date.dt.to_period('M')])
.values
.apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
.reset_index()
.rename({'date': 'YearMonth'}, axis=1)
)
   ID YearMonth  values
0   0   2017-01      55
1   1   2017-01      78
```

Comment: This solution is great but my problem is that this command `df['YearMonth'] = df.date.dt.to_period('M')` takes infinite time and I don't know why

Comment: It is `(56462685, 3)`

Comment: 54 million rows would explain why `.dt.to_period` takes a little while. On my mid-2015 MacBook Pro, 5.4 million rows of random dates takes ~8 s. Try giving it a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a year month column and then group

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['YearMonth'] = df.date.dt.to_period('M')
df.groupby('ID')['YearMonth','values'].apply(lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0]).reset_index()


    ID  YearMonth   values
0   0   2017-01     55
1   1   2017-01     78
```

If you want the most frequent value by ID and yearmonth, change the last line to

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'YearMonth'])['values'].apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0]).reset_index()
```

If you are not able to convert date column to period, use

```
df.groupby(['ID', df.date.dt.year.rename('Year'), df.date.dt.month.rename('Month')])['values'].apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0]).reset_index()

    ID  Year    Month   values
0   0   2017    1       55
1   1   2017    1       78
```

Comment: This solution is great but my problem is that this command `df['YearMonth'] = df.date.dt.to_period('M')` takes infinite time and I don't know why.

Comment: @emax, I hope this doesn't come off as insulting, but upvoting the answer would have taken less time than typing that comment :P

Comment: @emax, even for the dummy dataset, grouping over year and month (my last solution) is taking 4.6 ms vis-a-vis 8.66 ms with my original solution using to_period