# How to count frequency monthly in dataframe phyton

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

i'm learning python but i'm having trouble combining daily frequency into monthly frequency as below

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 |
| 2020-01-02 | 2 |
| 2020-01-03 | 0 |
| ... | ... |
| 2021-01-01 | 0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 3 |

how to make the **dataframe** above (data per daily) be like below (Data Per Monthly)

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Jan-2020 | 15 |
| Feb-2020 | 25 |
| ... | ... |
| Jan-2021 | 21 |
| Feb-2021 | 15 |

Comment: i think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52302794/8178422) can help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas groupby month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646191/pandas-groupby-month-and-year)